# How to Control media player android while Playing Rtsp Link on Samsung Galaxy S3?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, rtsp, live-streaming, rtsp-client

I have made a small app for playing live stream.It is working good on other devices but on Samsung Galaxy S3 can not control the media player. I am using media player using the following code

```
sdrPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                sdrPlayer.setOnErrorListener(video.this);
                sdrPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(video.this);
                sdrPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(video.this);
                sdrPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(video.this);
                sdrPlayer.setDataSource(video.this, Uri.parse(url));
                sdrPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                sdrPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
                sdrPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

but media player is throwing the issue `media player error (1, -110)` but I do not know the meaning of this error and also there is no proper documentation. I found this [documentation](https://github.com/android/platform_external_opencore/blob/master/pvmi/pvmf/include/pvmf_return_codes.h) but I can not get the error and also media player starts playing a bit late after calling start function in on prepare listener.I can not control the pause and play of the stream.
Any kind of help will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough of information. I think adding more code, may be even full file, would help. As per my experience, S3 is less troublesome device on playing rtsp streams, I have created rtsp player too. You might have done something wrong. Let's also ask what the stream you are trying to play, hls, anything else?

You could also do the following:

1. try to play the stream with some desktop player: quicktime, mplayer.
   Do they play it right?
2. try to validate the stream with one of those rtsp streams validators, do they find it ok?